# Why won't my menu open on mobile devices?

Tags: html, css, menu

I work for this organization (Vibro) as responsible for the webpage. Today I was told that our website menu won't open on mobile devices. Here's our page: www.vibro.no/
Can you see any errors with this?

Thanks for replies!

Comment: You get `general.js?ver=1523095733:1 Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function at general.js?ver=1523095733:1`

Do you have jquery correctly installed?

Comment: I think so, but I made some changes a few days ago that maybe created the error. I'll see if I can change it.

Comment: I didn't delete my code, but it didn't change anything now that I've deleted it

Comment: Can you see where Typeerror is?

Comment: I fixed it! Was just my code that I put up a few days a go that did the error. So I deleted it, and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that it was some changes in general.js that I did a few days a go that made the error. So now that the code is deleted, the menu button works fine.